# How to test if Qore object is inherited from a specific class

Tags: qore

When I have more classes, how can I test if instance is derived from a class?

```
class a {
};
class b inherits a {
};
class c inherits b {
};


a B = new b();
a C = new c();
assert ((B is instance_of b) == (C is instance_of b))
```

Ugly hack is testing *B.className == 'b'* but it is wrong for *'C'*. I cannot find an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [instanceof](https://docs.qore.org/current/lang/html/operators.html#instanceof) operator:

```
class A {
}
class B inherits A {
}
class C inherits B {
}

A a();
B b();
C c();

printf("%y %y %y\n", a instanceof B, b instanceof B, c instanceof C);
```

prints: `False True True`

(the code above is based on your code but follows Qore's standard [naming conventions](https://github.com/qorelanguage/qore/wiki/Naming-Conventions) and was also corrected for syntax errors)

Comment: `printf("%y %y %y\n", a instanceof B, b instanceof B, c instanceof B);` is the case I need. It works!